# Singly Linked List - C

Tags: c

I have a really quick question about singly linked lists, which I could not find the answer to in other questions.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int data);
void printList();

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * link;
};

struct node * head = NULL;

main()
{
    char c; 

    while ((c = getchar()) != 'q')
    {
        if (c == 'a')
        {
            int temp;

            printf("data: ");
            scanf("%d", &temp);

            add(temp);
        }

        if (c == 'p')
            printList();
    }
}

void add(int data)
{
    struct node * temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "error");

    temp->link = head;
    temp->data = data;
    head = temp;
}

void printList()
{
    struct node * temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "error");

    temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}
```

Now, I have been told that I need to create a function or a scenario inside my add function that does something differently if a new list is being created. In other words, when the list is empty, and the first element is being added to it, it needs to be done differently from when a populated list is receiving another node at the front. I found an example of such code online:

```
# // Adding a Node at the Beginning of the List  
#   
# void addBeg(int num)  
# {  
#    struct Node *temp;  
#   
#    temp=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
#    temp->Data = num;  
#   
#    if (Head == NULL)  
#    {  
#       //List is Empty  
#       Head=temp;  
#       Head->Next=NULL;  
#    }  
#    else  
#    {  
#       temp->Next=Head;  
#       Head=temp;  
#    }  
# }
```

As you will notice, if the list is empty, the head node is populated.

My code works fine, but I am wondering if I am overlooking something with regards to handling the null head situation.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your add() function works but it seg faults if malloc fails. You should `return` if `temp == NULL`. You need not to malloc a new node in print too, simply using a pointer to the head would be enough. Memory is leaking

Comment: Your printList function has a bug: it mallocs a new temp node, and then immediately overwrites the malloc'd pointer with the head pointer, thus leaking the allocated node. The allocation is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your `add()` function. The case where `head == NULL` needs no special treatment.

As others have noticed, your error checking is not correct because you need to return from the function in case `malloc` fails.  As it stands your `add()` function carries on an attempts to assign to `*temp` when `temp` is `NULL`.

The code you showed with such special treatment is bogus. The `else` clause in that code works perfectly well when `head == NULL`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I find it quite odd how I was taught to do them separately in school. Oh well!

Comment: Alright, so the way I understand it, my code is fine. It's just best to check for instances of null, but otherwise, my program should not generate any unexpected glitches? Thanks again all!

Comment: @seyelent You only need to check for NULL if you are going to dereference. If you intend to assign something that may be NULL to a pointer, then you don't need any special treatment.

Comment: "but otherwise, my program should not generate any unexpected glitches?" Well, see the comments to the question for some glitches.

Answer (score 1):

You have a choice between checking if your pointer on head is null every time you use it or you can assume that it isn't null if you treated head node differently.

Good manners presume that you should check it always, but if you don't check and don't dereference null pointers then your code will work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will always run the line (when adding a node)

```
head = temp;
```

You will never have a NULL reference in your head node after you've added the node.  This is because you verify above (temp != null) that temp is not a null pointer.

Now when searching for a node, it would be a really good idea to check that the head node is not null before you go accessing fields in whatever it (doesn't) point to.  Perhaps that's what was meant in the "special conditions" and the notes were mixed up with this case where it is not generally necessary.

Comment: Well... unless temp is `NULL`.

Comment: In which case the code would have exited four lines above.  Coding (like chess) requires that you both focus on the local happenings and the distant happenings which can affect the local happenings.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider `addBeg` if branch:

```
if (Head == NULL)  
{  
   Head=temp;  
   Head->Next=NULL;  
}  
else  
{  
   Head=temp;  
   temp->Next=Head;  
}
```

you see that you are assigning `temp` to `head` and then setting the `next` pointer.
Your implementation is, on the other hand:

```
temp->link = head;
temp->data = data;
head = temp;
```

and if you skip the `data` part (and `head = temp` which is present in both cases), you will readily see that it is equivalent to the first one, because

```
temp->link = head;
```

is the same as:

```
if (Head == NULL)  
{  
   Head->Next=NULL;  
}  
else  
{  
   temp->Next=Head;  
}
```

Comment: When `Head == NULL`, `Head->Next = NULL` will surely crash the program.

Comment: @larsmans: bad of me! you are right, I edited my answer, the reasoning still holds...