# How can a Linked List be implemented using only pointers (w/o structures)?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list without using structures in C.
I want to be able to store an `int` variable on every node and a pointer to the next node, add unlimited numbers to the list, remove the first item, print all of the elements, etc.

I was thinking that every node of type `int**` should have 2 pointers of type `int*`.
the first one will point to an `int` address and the second will point to `NULL`.
Then, if I like to add a number to the list, I'll use the last pointer to point to a new allocated node of type `int**` and so on.

I'm having trouble writing the proper code for this though, and can't seem to reach to the actual `int` values. See the image below:
[image: explanation]

Comment: What exactly is the point of this exercise? It seems to me that all it would achieve would be creating really messy code without any advantages over simply using `struct`s

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846844/singly-linked-list-c

Comment: Seems a bit odd that you don't want to store an `int` data value but the more complicated `int*` to a data value somewhere else. Is the data in the linked list being altered on the fly?

Comment: Since I need the memory to be able to store the pointer to the next node I guessed I have to make a pointer to an int variable since as far as I know you can't store different types of data on the same array.

Comment: @Infected: you are already storing different types: an `int*` and an `int**` (the pointer to the next node). OK, both are pointers, but not pointers to the same base type. In *some* environments, these are not of the same size.

Comment: It simply makes no sense *not* to use a `struct`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I know it doesn't make any sense, that's the part of the exercise though.

Comment: I guess you could fake using `struct`s via a `char*`, allocating enough memory for an `int` and another `char*` (to the next node) and doing a bit of pointer arithmetic. It's rather unsafe though. (I guess you could do something similar with an `int**` but I still don't see the point)

Comment: @Infected: Tell the person who gave you that exercise that it makes no sense. <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution of a LinkedList managed as int ** pointers.

**Step 1** - the `addNode()` function to add one node to the `int **head`.

```
int **addNode(int **head, int ival)
{
    int **node = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));

    // don't forget to alloc memory to store the int value
    node[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(node[0]) = ival;
    // next is pointing to NULL
    node[1] = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        // first node to be added
        head = node;
    }
    else {
        int **temp;

        temp = head;
        // temp[1] is the next
        while (temp[1]!=NULL) {
            // cast needed to go to the next node
            temp = (int **)temp[1];
        }
        // cast needed to store the next node
        temp[1] = (int *)node;
    }
    return (head);
}
```

**Step 2** - a function `display()` to explore the current linkedlist.

```
void display(int **head)
{
    int **temp;
    int i = 0;

    temp = head;
    printf("display:\n");
    while (temp!=NULL) {
        // temp[0] is pointing to the ivalue
        printf("node[%d]=%d\n",i++,*(temp[0]));
        temp = (int **)temp[1];
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Step 3** - the `popNode()` function to remove the first node.

```
int **popNode(int **head)
{
    int **temp;

    if (head!=NULL) {
        temp = (int **)head[1];
        // don't forget to free ivalue
        free(head[0]);
        // then free the next pointer
        free(head[1]);
        head = temp;
    }
    return (head);
}
```

**Step 4** - then an example of `main()` function using the linkedlist.

```
int main()
{
    int **head = NULL;

    head = addNode(head,111);
    head = addNode(head,222);
    head = addNode(head,333);

    display(head);
    // display:
    // node[0]=111
    // node[1]=222
    // node[2]=333

    head = popNode(head);

    display(head);
    // display:
    // node[0]=222
    // node[1]=333

    while ((head = popNode(head))!=NULL);

    display(head);
    // display:

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by allocating two `uintptr_t` each time: the first allocated memory space will be responsible for storing the value of the integer and the second one will be pointing to the next memory location.

```
uintptr_t nodeFirst = malloc(2 * sizeof(uintptr_t));
...
...
uintptr_t nodeNext = malloc(2 * sizeof(uintptr_t));
....
....
*nodeFirst = someIntValue;
*(nodeFirst + 1) = nodeNext;
...
```

The fact is, my solution above is still using the struct analogy, but w/o the `struct` keyword.

Comment: I have to use only pointers without any type of structures. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: @Infected this code is doing exactly what you described in your image. If that is not allowed that means your requirement cannot be fullfilled.

Comment: In the above code, there is no "type of structure". Each node is a pointer to an array of two pointers. The first points to the payload, the second to the next node. It is impossible to do this with *only* pointers. Some allocation will have to be performed. Are you sure you are actually understanding the exercise correctly?

Comment: I meant that I can't use uintptr_t, malloc is allowed

Comment: Then use `int **` instead.

Comment: Assuming you have a conventional 32 bits system, which evaluates `sizeof(int) == sizeof(uintptr_t)` to `true`, then you can replace `uintptr_t` with `int`.

Answer (score -1):

Allocate two arrays, both of which are stored as pointers.  In C, they can be the pointers you get back from `calloc()`.  The first holds your node data.  We can call it `nodes`.  The second is an array of pointers (or integral offsets).  We can call it `nexts`.  Whenever you update the list, update `nodes` so that each `nexts[i]` links to the next node after the one that contains `nodes[i]`, or an invalid value such as `NULL` or `-1` if it is the tail.  For a double-linked list, you’d need `befores` or to use the XOR trick.  You’ll need a head pointer and some kind of indicator of which elements in your pool are unallocated, which could be something simple like a first free index, or something more complicated like a bitfield.

You would still need to wrap all this in a structure to get more than one linked list in your program, but that does give you one linked list using no data structure other than pointers.

This challenge is crazy, but a structure of arrays isn’t, and you might see a graph or a list of vertices stored in a somewhat similar way.  You can allocate or deallocate your node pool all at once instead of in small chunks, it could be more efficient to use 32-bit offsets instead of 64-bit next pointers, and contiguous storage gets you locality of reference.